# Stop TCP Listener

Tags: vb.net, tcplistener

When I stop my TCP Listener by the Stop command, I always get an error because I use BeginAcceptTcpClient to accept the clients. How can I stop a listener properly?

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN Documentation for [TcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient.aspx).

> The asynchronous BeginAcceptTcpClient operation must be completed by calling the [EndAcceptTcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.endaccepttcpclient.aspx) method. Typically, the method is invoked by the callback delegate.

Comment: But how can I call this method if I don't have a IAsyncResult, I could pass to it?

Comment: use the IAsyncResult returned by the BeginAcceptTcpClient Method

Comment: Give this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx) a read.